# Facebook API Get Number Of Friends For Userid

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the number of friends for a userid, I can see that this userid is a friend but how do I get there total number of friends?

I have tried using the /{user-id}/friends endpoint but I get a privilege error. Using /{user-id-a}/friends/{user-id-b} I just get my friend data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `/{user_id}/friends`. Therefore you need to gather the `user_friends` permission during the login dialog of your app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends/

The response for the call will contain a field `summary.total_count` with the total number of friends this `user_id` has. Keep in mind that only the friends which are also using the same app will be returned in the friends data array. If you just want the total count, the info returned should be sufficient.

Comment: the /{user_id}/friends returns an empty dataset because the user_id is not my user_id

Comment: If you have the user's Access Token, you can call /me/friends. Otherwise you'll never be able to access this data, because it requires the permission of the individual User.